# Get string result from PHP code using Sencha Touch 2 Ajax request

Tags: php, javascript, sencha-touch

I'm writing a mobile application and want to get the user's IP address using PHP and Ajax with Sencha touch 2.

At the moment the Ajax request is returning success, but the responseText is all of the code inside the php file.

This is my php code in a file called action.php:

```
<?php
function getIPAddress()
{
    if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP']))   
    {
      $ip=$_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
    }
    elseif (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']))  
    {
      $ip=$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
    }
    else
    {
      $ip=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    }
    return $ip;
}

?>
```

and this is my ajax request:

```
Ext.Ajax.request({
        url : 'action.php?',
        success : function(response, options) {
            console.log('success ' + response.responseText);
        },
        failure : function(response, options) {
            console.log('failure ' + response);
        }
    });
```

The console prints out "success " along with the exact text from the php file. How do I get the IP address from the php file? Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the function and echo the results so it is returned within the AJAX request.

```
<?php
function getIPAddress()
{
    if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP']))   
    {
      $ip=$_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
    }
    elseif (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']))  
    {
      $ip=$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
    }
    else
    {
      $ip=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    }
    return $ip;
}
echo getIPAddress();
?>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm still experiencing the same problem. It just prints out the 'echo getIPAddress();' part as well now. I'm not sure if the ajax method is calling the function correctly.